# Where did this Data folder come from?

Tags: macos

Does anyone know where this folder came from? I don't believe that I created it, but it doesn't seem that it comes by default because there is nothing in it. The folder I'm referring to is the one titled Data in case that was not clear. Thanks for any ideas you may have.

[image: the folder]

Comment: What's in the folder?  It was likely created by an app?

Comment: Does the Creation Date give you any clues?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup, then go ahead and delete the folder. You are correct that it's not something Apple installs. Lots of third party database software like `mongodb` work best with a /data mount point - so if you can correlate the creation date on that folder with running an install script or package you might be able to infer which process created that folder.

There isn't an auditing system you can read to determine when or what installed a change generally - so use Finder to get information on the folder or perhaps try a tool like [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/) to check receipts - maybe you will be lucky with a package claiming the creation of that /Data directory.